# Order by Cast not working on Cpanel

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, cpanel, php-5.6

Can you help me? I am trying to get the an ordered result. using this line of code

```
order by cast(score as int) desc
```

In my xampp they are working fine but when I upload to my cpanel it does not work anymore. Please help

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "tabulati_user";
$password = "Star51@#";
$dbname = "tabulati_ats";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$catId = $Categories->id;
$sqlRank = "SELECT *  FROM rankings where catId='".$catId."' and judId='".$judgeId."' order by cast(score as int) desc";
$resultRank = $conn->query($sqlRank);
```

Comment: You need to be more specific than "it does not work".  What _is_ happening? Are you getting errors? If so, what are they? Are you getting a result, but it's just not the one you expect? If so, what is the expected result and what is the actual result? Before you go any further though, I'd _highly_ suggest that you rewrite your query to use bound parameters.

Comment: it does not display any result please help

Comment: in my xampp.. it display results.. but when I upload in live server their is no result been displayed..